# Error with with namespace referencing in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello all am a freshman to MVC 5 and am trying to achieve a project by following a particular video tutorial. In this tutorial I was asked to create folders in Area for Users, Admin, Common and Security. We added BOL using database first Approach. in other to interact with this BOL we added a controller class in Users  controller folder and name It index for us to create a get form for submitting details with form. this approach lead to scaffolding template for getting a form. Now at the point of running my project to see the form created an error is being displayed..

[image]

My Index.cshtml is as follow:

[image]

[Controller][3]

[Folder Arrangement in area][4]

Comment: your controller code and view code should be in `code section`..

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-do-i-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page