# Asp.net MVC Razor apply filter to response texts

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to apply a simple filter to any text that will be printed to page using razor command `@`.
in example see below codes:

```
public static class MyHelper
{
    public string MyFilter(this string txt)
    {
        return txt.Replace("foo", "bar");
    }
}
```

**in this .cshtml view file**

```
@{
    var text = "this is foo!!";
}
<div>@text</div>
```

I expect somehow to print `this is bar!!` instead of `this is foo!!`

Comment: You can create `HtmlHelper` for this purpose.

Comment: Why would you do that in the view as opposed to in the controller (where it should be done)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke because the text that will be printed could be in a dataset or a variable or whatever possible and I think it's more simple to apply filter to razor response than run a function on each field of rows of a dataset.

Comment: Your logic should be done in the controller, not the view (and your cant just _apply a filter to razor response_)

Comment: How does your view know to use the `MyFilter` method?  From what I see, you are simply creating a variable called `text` and then assigning it a string.. then displaying it in the view... You are not using the `MyFilter` method whatsoever in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AdilMammadov said you can use [`HtmlHelper`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) for that.

Simple C# class with `static` method:

```
using System;
namespace MvcApplication1.MyHelpers
{
    public class MyHelpers
    {
        public static string FooReplacer(string txt)
        {
            return txt.Replace("foo", "bar");
        }
    }
}
```

And use the helper in your view:

```
@using MvcApplication1
...
<p>@MyHelpers.FooReplacer("foo foo")</p> <!--returns <p>bar bar</p>-->
```

Comment: In the view you have to specify the model.. why are you using a `using` statement in the View?  That should be changed to `@model MvcApplication1.MyHelpers`.. then when you call the `FooReplacer` method you just have to do `Model.FooReplacer("foo foo")`

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid You're right that I can use `@model MvcApplication1.MyHelpers` but as I know my approach is also works fine http://stackoverflow.com/a/3244924/1821692

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are close.  The only problem is that your View doesn't know to use your filter because you didn't specify that within your View.

This should work:

**Model**

```
public static class MyHelper
{
    public string MyFilter(this string txt)
    {
        return txt.Replace("foo", "bar");
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model AssemblyName.MyHelper

@{
    Layout = null;
    var text = Model.MyFilter("Let's go to the foo");
}
<div>@text</div>

// will display "Let's go to the bar"
```

I have created a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wEnpfu) for you, to show that this will work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please mark either one of the answers provided as accepted so that this question can be marked as answered!