# Doesn't contain definition for 'Books'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am currently making a small application with basic CRUD operations and I want to display all Books in my View. But when I call `.Books`object it's written that:

> 'IndexModel' does not contain a definition for 'Books' and no accessible extension method 'Books' accepting a first argument of type 'IndexModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is what I did so far:

**Book Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CRUD_Razor_2_1.Model
{
    public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string ISBN { get; set; }

        public string Author { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CRUD_Razor_2_1.Model
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Index.html.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CRUD_Razor_2_1.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace CRUD_Razor_2_1.Pages.BookList
{
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public CreateModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        [BindProperty]
        public Book Book { get; set; }


        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            _db.Books.Add(Book);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

And here when I want to call `Model.Book.Count()` is where I get the error:

```
@page
@model IndexModel;


@{
}

<br />
<h2>Book List</h2>
<br />

<a asp-page="Create" class="btn btn-primary">Create New Book</a>

@if(Model.Books.Count() > 0)
{

}
else
{

}
```

Comment: *"And here when I want to call Model.Book.Count()I get error"* but you are calling Model.Book***s***.Count(). (notice the "s")

Comment: Where is `IndexModel`? You've included code for `CreateModel` but not `IndexModel`.

Comment: Sometimes you will be forced to have using directions also in razor templates. Some guide is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-do-i-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page

Comment: I notice that my IndexModel has been deleted, that's why I have problem. No everything is Ok.
Thank you guys :)