# How do I reference my packages in my Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

```
Install-Package popper.js -Version 1.16.1
```

How do I use it within my cshtml file? I looked in wwwroot and I don't see any folders created?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-do-i-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page

Comment: Sorry, I think i was confused by your question. The comment above doesn't apply. Since this is a client-side library, why not load it just like any other `js` library? I don't think using nuget makes sense here.

Comment: so what is the point of doing NuGet package installs for Client side libraries? I am a little confused about this.

Comment: I don't think there is a point to it. I'm not even sure why that library is in nuget. There is some built-in management of client-side libraries in VS if you want to manage it from within VS instead of just using npm. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: @Bodacious can you mark your comment as an Answer

Comment: No, but I can submit an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why a client-side package is even in NuGet, to be honest. You should just install this like you would any other client-side js package, using npm or whatever you prefer.

There is some built-in management of client-side libraries in VS if you want to manage it from within VS instead of just using npm.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.1