# How to use dll in view page in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dllimport

I am trying to import the dll files in view page but i have no idea how to import the dll files in view directly without using controller. Anyone have an idea about it please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import a namespace in Razor View Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-do-i-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume your talking about Razor view in mvc.

Top Of Your View

```
@using Namespace.Reference.Of.Your.Library;
```

Also add your specific namespace reference within your web.config

```
<add namespace="here" />
```

Don't forget to set the Copy Local property to "True" in your dll.

Comment: Note: COM components is not supported but can still be called in using statements