# Razor view @model can't find type or namespace name "x"

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, razor

I am trying to get a razor view model to work for a test website, but I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong. I keep getting the error when trying to use a `IEnumerable` from the class I'm sending the collection with. It keep giving the error:

> The type or namespace name 'x' could not be found (are you missing a
> using directive or and assembly reference?)

This is the code in the index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Sweater>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
```

Comment: Try to define full clarified namespace of the `Sweater`. Like `@model IEnumerable<Namespace.Of.The.Sweater>`, or add `@using` directive. See [https://stackoverflow.com/q/3239006/6630084](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3239006/6630084)

Comment: it does not seem to find the namespace at all., i have a screenshot but i don't know how to post it

Comment: aaah nvm i fixed it!

Comment: This is why sometimes considered posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). :)