# Why storing the date like dd-MMM-yyyy is getting converted to dd-MM-yyyy?

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

I have a very different kind of problem.

I have deployed my mvc application to live server.

It has date time format like this '01/07/2019'.

I have a textbox which is populated from jquery datetimepicker. It populates like this 27/Jul/2019 but in sql table it stores like `2019-07-17 00:00:00.000`
and after binding the data from database to textboxfor, it appears like this 27-07-2019.

And upon saving it throws error for all the dates that are greater than 12 as a day e.g. `13/07/2019` but for 13/Jul/2019 it works good.

how to tackle this?

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionReport.InspectionDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control  input-sm pull-right text-box single-line" } })
```

jquery:

```
$("#InspectionReport_InspectionDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/M/yy' });
```

class:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Inspection Date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0: dd-MMM-yyyy}")]
public DateTime InspectionDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Have you checked the culture info that you've got set in IIS? We had a similar issue where dates were being parsed using the wrong culture.

Comment: how to check that?

Comment: isn't there any date format that won't need any further settings?

Comment: Try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100061/how-to-configure-invariant-culture-in-asp-net-globalization

Comment: Web servers are generally set to run in UTC timezone and US (or invariant) cultures.  You can set your code to always run in whatever culture you require (somewhere in startup), or you can write code that allows the user of the web site to decide which culture they would prefer.  Supporting multiple timezones/cultures is not an insignificant task.

Comment: The error ir because your sql server and the PC you are developing are not storing the dates the same way. You are trying to send something like (dd-MM-yyyy) but your sql server expects another string (perhaps MM-dd-yyyy, or yyyy-MM-dd).

Comment: Check [this page](https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/09/ms-sql-server-how-to-get-date-only-from-datetime-value.html), it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

In a date field of data type *DateTime(2)*, a date value is stored as a value with *no format*.

Thus, to display the value, apply the format you wish, or a  default format will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InspectionReport.InspectionDate, "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", htmlAttributes: new { @type="date" })
```